# LogParser subqueries for xml

Tags: xml, subquery, logparser

Does logparser support subqueries? Im trying to parse an XML, I can get all the items, but also I need another field that is outside items list and is the same for every item. So I need to add it as another colum with a subquery. Is that possible? 
THANKS A LOT

---

GREAT, finally I could found a work around (not the best, but it works)
By adding 2 times the same xml, but changing the node level. First I will get one single row all empty but with the value of channel at last column. Then I will get all the items row. This mixed data will be import to temp table at database, and there I will handle it.

```
FROM 
'F:\test.xml#/rss/channel/ctv:channel',
'F:\test.xml#/rss/channel/item';
```

Comment: I read that LogParser does not support subqueries, so is there any way to store a value in a variable and then use it in the query?

Comment: GREAT... finally I could found a work arround (not the best, but it works)

OM 
'F:\.....xml#/rss/channel/ctv:channel',
'F:\.....xml#/rss/channel/item';